# Mixing omniauth with another authentication system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restful-authentication, omniauth

I haven't been able to find a way to mix the OmniAuth authentication system (which rocks by the way) and a normal authentication system (like restful authentication).

Any info on this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Railscasts.com has some great screencasts showing how to integrate with Devise http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=omniauth

Also, Devise itself has a branch integrated with omniauth if you only need one authentication strategy: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/v1.2.oauth